# Meteor - Is it secure to limit Google logins by a list of allowed email domains?

Tags: security, meteor, google-authentication

In my Meteor app intended for our organization's internal use, I want users to be able to log in using their company-issued Google account. The only account package I have included is `accounts-google`, and I have this server-side code to check the email domains:

```js
const allowedDomains = ['company.com', 'company.io'];

Accounts.config({
  restrictCreationByEmailDomain: email =>
    allowedDomains.includes(email.replace(/.*@/, '')),
});
```

**Is this 100% secure?** Is there any way a user could fool the Google accounts package of their email address, or have an email address on their Google account that would pass the above validation, even though it's not issued by our organization?

Answer (score 1):

Although nothing is 100% secure, this appears like it meets your needs.

An email address like `"Abc@company.com"@example.com` won't be able to bypass it, because your regexp takes everything up to the last `@`, so in this case will look for a string match against `example.com` and fail validation.

Of couse I'm assuming that you are validating that the registered user can access mails sent to their entered address before you allow them to access your application.